# Javascript code added in the div section of html code does not show anything.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visualization

This is the code I am using to visualize the bar chart I am trying to get from the dataset I am using. But it is not showing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">



        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.layout.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
.chart {
display: block;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
}

text {
 font-size: 11px;
}

rect {
fill: none;
}

div.bar {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 75px;   /* Gets overriden by D3-assigned height below */
            background-color: teal;
            margin-right: 2px;
        }

.axis path,
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: black;
          shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .axis text {
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 11px;
        }


</style>

</head>



<body>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-4 img-responsive"><img src="img/e2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100"></div>


            <div class="col-md-4" >
            <div id="body">
              <div id="footer">
                <h3>Course Scheduler TreeMap</h3>
                <div class="hint">click or option-click to descend or ascend</div>
                <div><select>
                  <option value="size">Size</option>
                  <option value="count">Count</option>
                </select></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-4" >
                <h1 >Plan Your Courses</h1>

            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Implementation of SVG Work</h2>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5, 26, 11, 8, 25, 14, 23, 19,
            14, 11, 22, 29, 11, 13, 12, 17, 18, 10,
            24, 18, 25, 9, 3 ];


       //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 100;
            var barPadding = 1;   // <-- New!

          /*  var dataset =[] ;
            for (var i =0; i<25; i++) {
                var newNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 25);
                dataset.push(newNumber);
            }*/

       //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        // GENERATING RECTANGLES AND MAKING BAR CHART

             svg.selectAll("rect")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length);
            })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h- (d*5);
           })
           .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
           .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d*5;
           })
           .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
            });

    // APPENDIND TEXT INTO THE BAR CHART

        svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                return d;
           })
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length) + 3;
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - (d * 4) + 10;
           })
           .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
           .attr("font-size", "11px")
           .attr("fill", "white");


    </script>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**-------**
However the same code is working when there is no div thing in html used and the whole javascript code is written in the body.
Here is the code that is working fine.

**--------**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Bar Char Test</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>

            <style type="text/css">

                div.bar {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 20px;
                    height: 75px;   /* Gets overriden by D3-assigned height below */
                    background-color: teal;
                    margin-right: 2px;
                }

            </style>


        </head>


        <body>

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
           var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5, 26, 11, 8, 25, 14, 23, 19,
                    14, 11, 22, 29, 11, 13, 12, 17, 18, 10,
                    24, 18, 25, 9, 28 ];


               //Width and height
                    var w = 500;
                    var h = 120;
                    var barPadding = 1;   // <-- New!


               //Create SVG element
                    var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

                // GENERATING RECTANGLES AND MAKING BAR CHART

                     svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .enter()
                   .append("rect")
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return i * (w / dataset.length);
                    })
                   .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return h- (d*5);
                   })
                   .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                   .attr("height", function(d) {
                        return d*5;
                   })
                   .attr("fill", function(d) {
                        return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
                    });

            // APPENDIND TEXT INTO THE BAR CHART

                svg.selectAll("text")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .enter()
                   .append("text")
                   .text(function(d) {
                        return d;
                   })
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return i * (w / dataset.length) + 3;
                   })
                   .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return h - (d * 4) + 10;
                   })
                   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                   .attr("font-size", "11px")
                   .attr("fill", "white");


            </script>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Comment: Can you add a Fiddle?

Comment: What is this Fiddle ?

Comment: but your code is different, in one you only have d3, in another you have many ext scripts. it perfectly possible that an error in one of them is killing the page and stopping your script. any errors in the first example? (in dev tools). you also have css (fill:none; etc) in one example and not the other

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net Paste your code there and send us the link.

Comment: I suspect you simply need to execute this when the page is ready, e.g. wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { .... });`

Comment: @AbraarArique i will try with this also, however it worked now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "rect" styling you are using will solve your purpose. Try removing the "rect" from styling section of css because you are using the "rect" thing from SVG.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the below css rule applied to `rect` element, which is hiding the bar, remove it and it should work fine

```
rect {
    fill: none;
}
```